# JavaScript REST client Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

Is there a JavaScript library which allow me to perform all the REST operation like (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` over `HTTP` or `HTTPS`)?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You don't really need a specific client, it's fairly simple with most libraries. For example in jQuery you can just call the generic `$.ajax` function with the type of request you want to make:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: 'ID=1&Name=John&Age=10', // or $('#myform').serializeArray()
    success: function() { alert('PUT completed'); }
});
```

You can replace `PUT` with `GET`/`POST`/`DELETE` or whatever.

Comment: jQuery also includes some handy shortcut methods for using GET and POST: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

Comment: and to expand on what @Avi Flax said, it's very simple to create your own `PUT` and `DELETE` methods if you want shortcuts.

Comment: How do you retrieve the body of the response? the headers?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis the `success` callback takes a `data` argument, that will contain the response.

Comment: @Soulseekah: Hmm... I didn't exactly get it. A simple example maybe? You mean success should become like success(data): function() {//do things with data}  ?

Comment: `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Technically, this is not a REST client, it's a HttpClient.  I'm looking for something that shows how to properly use link relations and media types to drive state.  Will keep looking...

Comment: Hey @aleemb, I have a similar request. I need to initiate a GET call but using Javascript only as our engine can only understand that. Is there a way I can rewrite this code to Javascript. I am not a jQuery guy..its kind of problem for me understanding this..

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy Hi Peter, if this is not what you were looking for, please try to not mark it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: @RhysO - err, this was not my question nor answer, I only commented...

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy oops sorry got the tone of your comment wrong... Apologies. You are right though.

Answer (score 72):

While you may wish to use a library, such as the excellent [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you don't have to: all modern browsers support HTTP very well in their JavaScript implementations via the [XMLHttpRequest API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest), which, despite its name, is not limited to XML representations.

Here's an example of making a synchronous HTTP PUT request in JavaScript:

```
var url = "http://host/path/to/resource";
var representationOfDesiredState = "The cheese is old and moldy, where is the bathroom?";

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

client.open("PUT", url, false);

client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

client.send(representationOfDesiredState);

if (client.status == 200)
    alert("The request succeeded!\n\nThe response representation was:\n\n" + client.responseText)
else
    alert("The request did not succeed!\n\nThe response status was: " + client.status + " " + client.statusText + ".");
```

This example is synchronous because that makes it a little easier, but it's quite easy to make asynchronous requests using this API as well.

There are thousands of pages and articles on the web about learning XmlHttpRequest — they usually use the term AJAX – unfortunately I can't recommend a specific one. You may find [this reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) handy though.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this jQuery plugin I just made :)
https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest/

Supports basic CRUD operations, nested resources, basic auth

```
  var client = new $.RestClient('/api/rest/');

  client.add('foo');
  client.foo.add('baz');
  client.add('bar');

  client.foo.create({a:21,b:42});
  // POST /api/rest/foo/ (with data a=21 and b=42)
  client.foo.read();
  // GET /api/rest/foo/
  client.foo.read("42");
  // GET /api/rest/foo/42/
  client.foo.update("42");
  // PUT /api/rest/foo/42/
  client.foo.delete("42");
  // DELETE /api/rest/foo/42/

  //RESULTS USE '$.Deferred'
  client.foo.read().success(function(foos) {
    alert('Hooray ! I have ' + foos.length + 'foos !' );
  });
```

If you find bugs or want new features, post them in the repositories 'Issues' page please

Comment: I like how simple you have made it.  It does appear to support additional options when you need them but you keep them out of the way.

Comment: Wow. You shared so many open sources. Respect.

Answer (score 8):

jQuery has [JSON-REST](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Rest) plugin with REST style of URI parameter templates. According to its description example of using is the followin: `$.Read("/{b}/{a}", { a:'foo', b:'bar', c:3 })` becomes a GET to "/bar/foo?c=3".

Answer (score 6):

For reference I want to add about ExtJS, as explained in Manual: [RESTful Web Services](http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Manual:RESTful_Web_Services). In short, use method to specify GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. Example:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/articles/restful-web-services',
    method: 'PUT',
    params: {
        author: 'Patrick Donelan',
        subject: 'RESTful Web Services are easy with Ext!'
    }
});
```

If the Accept header is necessary, it can be set as a default for all requests:

```
Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use mvc frameworks like Backbone.js that will provide a javascript model of the data. Changes to the model will be translated into REST calls.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [restful.js](https://github.com/marmelab/restful.js), a framework-agnostic RESTful client, using a syntax similar to the popular Restangular.

Answer (score 1):

Dojo does, e.g. via JsonRestStore, see http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/13/restful-json-dojo-data/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://adodson.com/hello.js/ which has

1. Rest API support
2. Built in support for many sites google, facebook, dropbox
3. It supports oAuth 1 and 2 support.