# Accessing REST Web Services through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, architecture, rest

First of all. I want to say that i've acctualy read the other posts ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921942/javascript-rest-client)) but, i don't think it's a good answer. I mean, what about all the status codes, and HyperMedia, etc. What about caching?

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree you do need error handling etc. I've been using Dojo, here's code from [my blog](http://djna.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/dojo-and-jax-rs-invocation-imprecation/)

```
var myEdition = {"Edition":{“author”:”x”, “title”"isbn":"44"}};
      var xhrArgs = {
                url: http://myhost/LibraryWink/library/editions,
                postData: dojo.toJson(myEdition),
                handleAs: "json",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                load: function(data) {
                    dojo.byId("mainMessageText").innerHTML
                           =  "Message posted.";
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    dojo.byId("mainMessageText").innerHTML
                            = "Error :" + error;
                }
            };
        dojo.byId("mainMessageText").innerHTML
                           = "Message being sent…"; 
        var deferred = dojo.rawXhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

The relevent points here being a). a framework such as dojo (orI guess jquery) helps b). there is handling for errors.

I also have [some thoughts](http://djna.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/whatever-can-go-wrong-error-handling-and-restful-services/) in general about REST services and error handling.

Comment: Great djna, i'll take a deeper look.