# Is it possible to upload files to Rackspace Files Cloud from browser?

Tags: amazon-s3, rackspace, rackspace-cloud

Is it possible to upload files to Rackspace Files Cloud from browser like in Amazon S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are speaking about uploading via the browser then you can use https://manage.rackspacecloud.com/ which has a nice web interface to upload your files.

If you want to have an API call from the browser since the API is all in REST it should not be too hard to implement it in JavaScript, I haven't seen  any library/binding in JavaScript but this should be pretty straightforward to do straight with jQuery or such, see this SO article for some examples :

[JavaScript REST client Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921942/javascript-rest-client)

and this is a link for the REST documentation of Rackspace CloudFiles :

http://docs.rackspacecloud.com/files/api/cf-devguide-latest.pdf

Comment: No, I mean API for browser upload.

Comment: That is not so simple. Because in this case it would be cross domain request to Rackspace cloud. So it will require HTML 5 CORS support from rackspace cloud.